# Glyph Sizes in FontForge SVG Importing

Tags: svg, fonts, fontforge

I created a set of svg glyphs for a font I am building, in Inkscape. 
They look fine in Inkscape, and fill the full canvas. But when I import them into FontForge, they appear tiny - around 1/10th of the size they should take up.

Can anyone explain why this is happening, and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some bugs in the FontForge.[This is a way to solve it.](http://ospublish.constantvzw.org/tools/import-inkscape-in-fontforge)

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your artboard in inkscape has many more units than the font's cartesian grid space.

1. Open Inkscape
2. From the File menu, select Document Properties.
3. Set units to pixels (px) and document dimensions to 1000 x 1000, click OK
4. Set a horizontal guide at 200px
5. Draw a glyph – the hardest part! :-)
6. Save the drawing as an SVG
7. Open FontForge
8. From the File menu, select Import, chose SVG, find your drawing, click OK

Inkscape now has a template, 'FontForge Glyph' that should make this more convenient.

Comment: What about glyph height/width? How much of the space should the icon and/or letter take up?